# Why not sample the session varibles of a PHP file that is in the same directory from another PHP file if it shows?

Tags: php, session, drupal, session-variables

I have a Drupal site

`mydomain.com/`

Within a block full php I have the following:

```
<?php
session_start ();
echo json_encode($_SESSION['playlist']); 
?>
```

This code shows me correctly my array inside the session varible
example:

```
[
    "{\"title\":\"emo\",\"artist\":\"a href=\",\"mp3\":\"\"}",
    "{\"title\":\"emo\",\"artist\":\"a href=\",\"mp3\":\"\"}",
    "{\"title\":\"Hablando Claro Pegando Fuerte\",\"artist\":\"\",\"mp3\":\"http://red.comppa.com/sites/default/files/audios/01%20radionovela%20hablando%20claro%20pegando%20fuerte.mp3\"}",
    "{\"title\":\"desobedicia\",\"artist\":\"a href=\",\"mp3\":\"\"}"
]
```

But if I have another file called `getsession.php` with the same code:

```
<?php
session_start ();
echo json_encode($_SESSION['playlist']); 
?>
```

Then I dirigo to `mydomain.com/getsession.php` and shows me:

```
null
```

Comment: Are you setting the session on the same page the same way on both files?

Comment: How does your Drupal installation handle sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved with :

```
<?php
//set the working directory 
chdir('/home/www/mydrupal/');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

//Load Drupal
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

echo json_encode($_SESSION['playlist']); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the order that your files are being included. It is possible that you are trying to echo the values of the session before it has been set.

Answer (score 0):

**session_start**

> If a session fails to start, then FALSE is returned. Previously TRUE
>   was returned. ([Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php))

**Perhaps, content was sent to the browser BEFORE session_start was called. This will generate an error as a result!**

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php) in a related post.